# Why exactly will this discord python command only run once?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I've been trying to get this code to work for a while;

```py
@bot.group()
async def donator(ctx):
    '''Commands for donators'''

@donator.command()
async def register(ctx, Steam_ID : str):
    '''Registers your donator status'''
    if SteamID(Steam_ID).is_valid():
        convert = SteamID(Steam_ID)
        Steam64ID = convert.as_64

        author = ctx.author

        with open('donators.json') as d:
            data = json.load(d)

        newstring = {
        f"{author.id}": {
                "steam": f"{Steam64ID}",
                "tier": "6"
            }
        }

        data.update(newstring)

        with open('donators.json', 'w') as d:
            json.dump(data, d, indent=2)

    else:
        ctx.send("Invalid Steam ID!\nThis command accepts any kind of Steam ID.")
```

When I run it, it will produce my desired result, a valid json file with the correct info is written, no errors.
If I run it again nothing happens, absolutely nothing. This is how the json is originally structured.

```json
{
  "000000000000000000": {
    "steam": "00000000000000000",
    "tier": "0"
  }
}
```

after running the python script it will look like this

```json
{
  "000000000000000000": {
    "steam": "00000000000000000",
    "tier": "0"
  },
  "240912491624923137": {
    "steam": "76561197960265729",
    "tier": "6"
  }
}
```

If I run it a second time, nothing happens. Nothing is written, the json file stays the same and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your JSON file as a list of dictionaries.

```
{"data": [{"id": 0, "name": "Hello"}, {"id": 1, "name": "Test"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My issue was not related to the JSON structure, in fact my current structure is working just fine. The issue was me trying to add multiple entries under the same account, so it would just update the already existing key instead of creating a duplicate.

Bad error on my part, whoops!

Comment: In that case, a duplicate cannot be created. Though you can edit an existing index.

Comment: No, no, I don't want duplicates, however I wasn't thinking straight and forgot that's how it worked haha! Was trying to make duplicates on the system I made that explicitly doesn't allow duplicates.